# How to type nested object in object literal

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css

I've got a tailwind.config.ts. I'd like to add type `DMSans-Regular` as a `ValidFont`. How can I achieve this?

```
type ValidFont = "DMSans-Regular"

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        md: "32px",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        primary: "DMSans-Regular"
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: What do you mean "add a type"? It's a JavaScript file.

Comment: `DMSans-Regular` is a string value here (the name of a typeface from the looks of it). Do you mean how to add another member to the `fontFamily` family structure?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Sorry for being unclear. I have updated the question. I've got a `ValidFont` that I want every value (where `primary` is the key and `DMSans-Regular` is the value) in `fontFamily` to adhere to `ValidFont`.

Comment: Give us an example of input/output usage

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mZXvJw) work for you?  I'm basing that off what you say in the comment and not in the question itself (so if you actually have multiple `ValidFont` values and multiple `fontFamily` members you might want to [edit] that into the example to avoid suggestions that won't work for you).  If that works I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the [`satisfies` operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) which will be released with TypeScript 4.9.  This lets you contextually interpret the `fontFamily` property as a `Record<string, ValidFont>`, meaning an object with any keys but whose properties are a `ValidFont`, without actually widening the property to that type and forgetting about the actual keys and values:

```
type ValidFont = "DMSans-Regular" | "Velveetica"

const exp = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        md: "32px",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        primary: "DMSans-Regular",
        secondary: "DMSans-Spicy", // error
        tertiary: "Velveetica"
      } satisfies Record<string, ValidFont>
    },
  },
};
```

If you need to do this before TypeScript 4.9 you can simulate the `satisfies` operator with a curried function like this:

```
const satisfiez = <T,>() => <U extends T>(u: U) => u

const exp = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontSize: {
        md: "32px",
      },
      fontFamily: satisfiez<Record<string, ValidFont>>()({
        primary: "DMSans-Regular",
        secondary: "DMSans-Spicy", // error
        tertiary: "Velveetica"
      })
    },
  },
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221018#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcgHYQCYFMEG4CwAofGATzHTgDUBDAG2FQDEIl4BeOAIgBEBZAZUqQBnALQAldAHMArtUpR2cAD4dy6agDd06GMADGldvny6mg+OgAeYOGwDe+OHBgALdCHQAuOPbyPHlmHQkVC8fPz8AMyYYXmAAL09vB3C-EBCOAGYAJjALdgAaZPCAX0LfFKjmekoQYGoiUKKUsChQOQaOHn4hMUkZOQKm8MF0E2D2ry4+ARFeMD0iArgAemW4dCgoaCG-QNhgCZU1TW09Ax3iuEFKHUEI4HRBOHETKFQAHjNWpAl8iho6IxmAA+JqlZLgvDFXAEPAgNAydAAOkskFgTzYqJhxlM8Gut3u6DiNjg7wAKvlgQAKACUNmBpIAqusLIFgk8ydSpF5GXSWAypEY8GMzCywFkSWEnK53I1yv5WUF0lLwpUYvFEiqUmlJtlcoN5X5ISk4GrqrV6l58cA7g84u8XtAPl9gD8-lRaAxosDqTSqVrwi02lAOlNuiJxNJZPIyibHCMxqhDmGZsI5gslqt1pttobwnsdMnVBotDp9IY83BijSwbGq2VoUKgA)